# How to Have Children Inherit Parent tabindex Value

Tags: html, angular, accessibility, tabindex

Is there a way to apply a parent's tabindex to all of it's children?

Example code:

```
<div id="app">
  <div tabindex="2" class="parent-section">
    Section 2
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-accent">test 2 a</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-accent">test 2 b</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-accent">test 2 c</a>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="1" class="parent-section flex-fill">
    Section 1
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-neutral">test 1 a</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-neutral">test 1 b</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-neutral">test 1 c</a>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="3" class="parent-section">
    Section 3
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-primary">test 3 a</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-primary">test 3 b</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-primary">test 3 c</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to focus first on section 1 div, and then each of it's selectable child elements WIHOUT SETTING A PARTICULAR TABINDEX ON EACH CHILD. The. it would tab to section 2, and so on.

I made a StackBlitz to demonstrate. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ypkxx3?file=index.html. You see you will tab to the section 1 div, section 2 div, and section 3 div first; and then it tabs through all the anchor elements.

This is a really basic example. I have an app with much more complex sections. Basically, I want to be able to set the tabindex of the section, and have it trickle down to all of it's focusable child elements. These sections are large and dynamic, so it wouldn't work if I have to add a particular tabindex on every single child element.

My actual application is an angular project.

Comment: using a `tabindex` attribute other than 0 or -1 is always a bad idea. Why do you want to confuse users who rely on the keyboard by having focus jump around in an illogical order? (And if you're using CSS to position these so that the tab order is in fact left-to-right, then you can surely reorder them in the DOM to avoid the tabindexes - which of course would make this question not arise.)

Answer (score 2):

First off, non-interactive elements, such as a `<div>` should not receive keyboard focus. That will be confusing to both keyboard users, who might think they can hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on the element since it received focus, and it will be confusing for screen reader users because a [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) and [label](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#name-role-value) ([accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name)) for the container won't be announced.

There is not a way to "inherit" the `tabindex` of a parent. You will have to set tabindex on all the children. You are allowed to have the same tabindex value for multiple elements. So your first container could have `tabindex="1"` for all the links and they will be processed first. When multiple elements have the same tabindex value, the browser will process them in the DOM order.

If you don't want to set the tabindex, then you'll need a keyboard event handler, perhaps on the `<body>` element, to override the browser's <kbd>tab</kbd> behavior. You would have to programmatically move the focus to the next element and then drain the event so that the browser doesn't try to move the focus.

Answer (score 0):

DOM order is really important in accessibility. So we should instead keep the items in order in the DOM and then change the visual order with CSS.

**Note:** 99% of the time "logical focus order" should go left to right (or RTL on RTL languages). I am assuming from the example given though that this is a general layout with 2 asides so it may be acceptable. **Please take this into consideration though before you implement the following.**

There is also a second point here, and that is that `tabindex` should hardly ever be greater than `0`.

If it is that means those items will be focusable first (so if you put this half way down a page the first <kbd>Tab</kbd> into the page would land at `tabindex="1"` and be confusing.

Finally by changing the `tabindex` to `0` it means we fixed your issue where the children elements are focused before the other parent elements as `tabindex="0"` doe not interfere with the natural focus order of the page.

### Using CSS to achieve your layout

We can use CSS flex `order` property to achieve your layout / request.

What we do is put the DOM order back to Section 1, Section 2, Section 3 and then use the `order` property to adjust the order that things are focused.

#### Example

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}

.parent-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-fill {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.parent-section,
.child-section {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.bg-neutral {
  background-color: rgb(253, 180, 237);
}
.bg-accent {
  background-color: rgb(180, 253, 202);
}
.bg-primary {
  background-color: rgb(253, 219, 180);
}

/* I gave each section an ID but you can use unique classes or `:nth-child` if you prefer */
#section1{
  order: 2;
}
#section2{
  order: 1;
}
#section3{
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<!-- notice that the sections are now in order within the DOM and I have changed the `tabindex` to 0 so it doesn't break DOM ordering -->
<div id="app">
  <section class="parent-section flex-fill" id="section1" tabindex="0">
    Section 1
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-neutral">test 1 a</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-neutral">test 1 b</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-neutral">test 1 c</a>
  </section>
  <aside class="parent-section" id="section2" tabindex="0">
    Section 2
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-accent">test 2 a</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-accent">test 2 b</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-accent">test 2 c</a>
  </aside>
  <aside  class="parent-section" id="section3" tabindex="0">
    Section 3
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-primary">test 3 a</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-primary">test 3 b</a>
    <a href="test.com" class="child-section bg-primary">test 3 c</a>
  </aside>
</div>
```